# HWIOAuthBundle - Instagram Signature

Tags: php, symfony, instagram, instagram-api, hwioauthbundle

Instagram has security verification that you can turn it on or off, and we what it on, its a `HMAC` using the `SHA256`.

This is the formula.

```
Token to sign: endpoint|key1=value1|key2=value2|...
Parameter name: sig
Parameter value: signed token with your Client Secret using the SHA256 hash algorithm
```

I placed a code in `HWIOAuthBundle -> GenericOAuth2ResourceOwner - > getUserInformation`

```
$sig = "/users/self";
$sig .= "|" . $this->options['attr_name'] . "=" . $accessToken['access_token'];
$sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $sig, $this->options['client_secret'], false);
```

Instagram is responding well and it works, but `HWIOAuthBundle` code fails with this warning, because that was not the parameters passed from the configuration, I forced the `sig=(SIGNATURE)` param.

> Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent

Anyone has any clue ?

---

## UPDATE

**Scratch that, the code did work.**

But, there has to be an easier way right ?

Comment: The guys from [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/806) just tag my comment as a Bug to be fixed.